# Connect to SQL inside doPost or doGet Java

Tags: java, html, mysql

I'm using Eclipse and am able to connect to a MySQL database and execute queries when running files as Java Applications but I can't find a solution anywhere for taking data from an HTML form and inserting it into a database.

When I send form data from HTML to Java I can run commands inside doPost or doGet, e.g. print out request.getParameter() values, but whenever I try and connect to a database from inside one of these I get "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" - - despite the fact I am able to connect to the database when running a separate Java application that isn't taking user input.

So I'm just wondering whether it is possible to take user data and input it into a database in this way through HTML and Java or would I need to use something like Swing JFrame with a DAO to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer at:  [Why am I getting "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908269/why-am-i-getting-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-test2/53821299#53821299).

If anyone else is having same problem you need to add:

private static final String DRIVER_NAME="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

at the top of the public class

and

try {

Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);

}  catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){

}

in the doPost or doGet function.

Maybe someone else is able to explain why you need these bits of code when the file is run as a result of passing data to it from an HTML form but you don't need the code when running the file as a Java Application?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the database drivers are being included in your deployed web application (.war). You can see the jar files that were included in the /lib directory of your deployed web application. Add the DB driver jar to the dependency list of your build.

Comment: I already had "mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" on the build path - if I didn't I don't think I'd be able to connect to the database when running java files as a Java Application inside Eclipse?  I exported my project and deployed one through Tomcat Manager App.  All I could think you might mean was that the .jar file needed to be in a lib folder in the WebContent folder -- the only folder you can see inside when opening deployed project, but doing this didn't change anything (as expected as don't .jar have effect when added to build?). Can you think of anything else that might be going wrong?